# PowerShell XAML ListBox Add_DoubleClick

Tags: powershell, xaml, listbox

Quick one. I want to add Add_DoubleClick() to ListBox in PowerShell, but this doesn't work with implemented ListBox via XAML file... and I'm stuck

I will be very grateful for any help here...

I still have msg warning, that my post is mostly code, so I need to write something here...

```
# $ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, PresentationCore, WindowsBase, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing 

$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$AssemblyLocation = Join-Path -Path $ScriptPath -ChildPath .\themes
foreach ($Assembly in (Dir $AssemblyLocation -Filter *.dll)) {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($Assembly.fullName) | out-null
}

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Controls:MetroWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    Title="ddd" 
    Height="500" 
    Width="800"
    BorderThickness="0" 
    GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Cyan.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>


    </Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="ListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="100" Margin="244,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112">
        <ListBoxItem Content="Coffie"></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
"@

#Read the form
$Reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
$Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader) 

#AutoFind all controls
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]")  | ForEach-Object { 
New-Variable  -Name $_.Name -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -Force 
}

$ListBox.Items.AddRange()
$ListBox.Add_DoubleClick({
$TextBox2.AppendText("dddd`r`n")
})
...`
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not enough information. What doesn't work? Are there errors? Does nothing happen?

Comment: Post all of the code to your form, please

Comment: Looking at the list of events on the WPF Listbox control, do you mean MouseDoubleClick?

Comment: @EBGreen nothing happen... I used MouseDoubleClick event and simple Add_Click... still nothing here... 

I edited op.

Answer (score 0):

I used different approach to my problem:

```
$smth.Add_IsMouseCapturedChanged({
 $smth.SelectedIndex = -1
})
```